# Cherry pick the good stuff from two commits, then create a new third commit

Tags: git

Here is the situation:

1. DevA made good additions to SomeFile.txt, then committed, and then pushed (AAA)
2. DevB pulled, **edited** the additions that DevA made, committed, and then pushed (BBB)
3. DevC pulled and wants to keep part of what DevA did and part of what DevB did.

How can DevC cherry pick changes from both AAA and BBB to create a new commit CCC?

Some Notes:

- We do not want to rewrite history.
- AAA would merge cleanly with BBB.

**ASCII graph**

```
CCC    (should include GoodIdeaA and GoodIdeaB)
 |
 | BBB (added GoodIdeaB, in the process deleted GoodIdeaA)
 | /
AAA    (added GoodIdeaA)
```

Note that BBB was done via a wholesale **copy-and-paste** operation. It *should* have been done via a merge.

Comment: What is the final aim? Will AAA and BBB be left there?

Comment: Yes. AAA and BBB should remain. I do not want to rewrite history.

Comment: This question needs an ASCII graph.

Comment: For the given ASCII graph: the `BBB` commit already contains changes from `AAA` and `BBB`. So nothing need to be done. And even more - you cannot cherry pick changes that are already here, just because changes are already here.

Comment: @zerkms When DevB edited, she introduced some good ideas of her own while also destroying some of DevA's good stuff.

Comment: @Shaun Luttin: so just modify `BBB` as you need and commit `CCC`. No extra steps are required here.

Comment: @zerkms Fair enough. How do I do that? E.g. merge AAA into BBB and create a new commit?

Comment: Just open your editor and start modifying files. I seriously cannot understand why you need something besides that.

Comment: @zerkms I'm a sucker for automation.

Comment: What do you want to automate? Recovering from "she introduced some good ideas of her own while also destroying some of DevA's good stuff"? Then you cannot do that, unless you can implement an AI as smart as you.

Comment: @zerkms It doesn't need sophisticated AI. Git merge would do the trick. The changes are not in merge conflict.

Comment: @Shaun Luttin: from what you have described: you want only some changes to keep. How would a script know which one? But now I see what you want - let's try modify your ASCII graph since it doesn't reflect your intentions. Done. Now it makes sense

Comment: @zerkms That's a good point. It might not be able to merge them automatically... what it could do is put git conflict markers into files. What I really want to do is create a merge between two commits and create a third commit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to take individual parts of the commits, you could use `git cherry-pick` with the `-n` option to avoid adding a commit:

```
   -n, --no-commit
       Usually the command automatically creates a sequence of commits.
       This flag applies the changes necessary to cherry-pick each named
       commit to your working tree and the index, without making any
       commit. In addition, when this option is used, your index does not
       have to match the HEAD commit. The cherry-pick is done against the
       beginning state of your index.

       This is useful when cherry-picking more than one commits' effect to
       your index in a row.
```

So something like this:

```
git cherry-pick -n AAA
git cherry-pick -n BBB
# Edit, clean up
git commit -m CCC
```